# Set up heads up for two people

Tags: keyboard, mouse, display

Is there a way to set up a Mac or Linux so that one can connect two mice and two keyboards with both users having independent input on the screen with their respective mice and keyboards?

I'd like to set up an environment for pairwise programming, and in particular have two developers be able to concurrently edit different documents on the same computer screen, but each person having different keyboards and mice.

I'd be much obliged for any input and direction.

Comment: As long as we're on the subject, does anyone know how to do the same thing on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Multi Pointer X on newer linux distros.  Here are some directions for [Ubuntu Lucid](http://ao2.it/en/blog/2010/01/19/poor-mans-multi-touch-using-multiple-mice-xorg)

Comment: @moshen - Thanks, that looks awesome. I can't see if two people can type in separate windows with that, though (and I presume not if they don't mention it). But darned cool.

Comment: I think it matters what window manager you're using with it.  There's supposed to be some preliminary support for Gnome, but you may have to hunt around.

Comment: Aye, I think there'd have to be some magic involved to set up single-head multi-focus... but hopefully someone's onto it. :)