# Set up a seperate multi-keyboard/mouse input

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, display, mouse

I'm trying to see if there's a way to get one machine on Windows with two displays with input devices relegated to their respective display.
I know there was one question similar to this but it was for mac: [Set up heads up for two people](https://superuser.com/questions/123216/set-up-heads-up-for-two-people)
How would I set up something like this on Windows 10?

Comment: try this: https://www.mousemux.com/